# Confused with simple mix of non-type templates and functions returning tuple

Tags: c++, tuples, variadic-templates

As exercise, I am trying to write 2 simple functions taking a non-type template int N.
The first one needs to create a tuple consisting of N copies of some object of type T. I would like it to resemble the following:

```
template <class T, int N> 
constexpr std::tuple<T...> fun(T t) {
  return (N > 0) ? std::tuple_cat(t, fun<T, N-1>(t)) : std::make_tuple(t);
}
```

I also tried something like this unsuccessfully (http://liveworkspace.org/code/3LZ0Fe).
I would like to be able to instantiate it with T = bool, say:

```
auto bools = fun<bool, 10> (false);
```

The second one should be a slight variation; I have a templated struct Foo and I would like to create a tuple containing a Foo< 0 >, ..., Foo< N >

```
template <int N> struct Foo {
   static const int id = N;
}

template <template <int> class T, int N> 
constexpr ??? fun2 (???) {...}
```

Since templated functions can't be partially specialized, I don't even know how to write a proper termination for my recursion.
I would like to do this completely statically without using **for** loops.

==================================================================================

Following Seth's suggestion I was stuck with writing the fun function itself which recursed infinitely:

```
template<typename T, int N>
typename fun_helper<T, N>::type 
fun(T t) {
  if (N > 0) 
    return typename fun_helper<T, N>::type 
      { std::tuple_cat(std::make_tuple(t), fun<T, N-1>(t)) };
  else return typename fun_helper<T, N>::type { };
}
```

By using an additional struct with a termination, I was able to get this working:

```
template<typename T, int N> struct fun {
  typename fun_helper<T, N>::type make(T t) {
    return typename fun_helper<T, N>::type 
      { std::tuple_cat(std::make_tuple(t), fun<T, N-1>().make(t)) };
  }
};

template<typename T> struct fun<T, 0> {
  typename fun_helper<T, 0>::type 
  make(T t) {
    return typename fun_helper<T, 0>::type { };
  }
};
```

The call is still relatively clumsy:

```
auto conds = fun<bool, 3>().make(false);
```

Is there a way to get it working without this additional struct ?

```
auto conds = fun<bool, 3>(false);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first, you can recursively build a parameter pack using `struct`s for partial specialisation (I show you this way because it relates to #2). This code isn't tested and doesn't take care of the default value for the elements, but it gives you the idea and the default value code can be easily added.

```
template<typename T, int N, typename... Rest>
struct fun_helper {
    typedef typename fun_helper<T, N - 1, T, Rest...>::type type;
};

template<typename T, typename... Rest>
struct fun_helper<T, 0, Rest...> {
    typedef std::tuple<Rest...> type;
};

template<typename T, int N>
typename fun_helper<T, N>::type fun() {
    return typename fun_helper<T, N>::type { };
}
```

For the second, you can combine the techniques above with a parameter pack of `int`s and use the `...` to expand them like

```
Foo<Ints>...
```

which expands to

```
Foo<Int1>, Foo<Int2>, ...
```

in your function.

Comment: Thanks Seth, I see the recursive type building now. Unfortunately I need a bit more hand holding, I cannot seem to build the first fun properly (i.e. given fun(T t) create the proper return object)...

Comment: @NickV actually that code works unmodified, you should call it like `auto t = fun<bool, 4>()` and it'll make `t` a `std::tuple<bool, bool, bool, bool>`.

Comment: yes it does. I was trying to write fun(T t). See my update above.

Comment: @NickV with the way you wrote it, could you not just move the call to .make() to inside a function? Also you should be able to eliminate the runtime recursion and expensive tuple_cat's by doing the same thing with values as you do with the types: use a template to recursively make N copies of the default value and make the final tuple at once.